# Ajax.actionLink returns the same result in IE

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement an `Ajax.ActionLink` in my `MVC4` website and for some reason I keep getting the same result in IE (Firefox works fine).
I added this to the bottom of my `_Layout.cshtml` page:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")  
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

(before adding the `jqueryval` line i kept getting redirected)
this is my ajax call:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}
<h2>Test</h2>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Click to get a new guid", "GetGuid",
new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "result",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    HttpMethod = "GET"
})
<div id="result">
</div>
```

**my controller action:**

```
public ActionResult GetGuid()
{
    string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    return PartialView("_guid", guid);
}
```

and the partial view:

```
@model String
<div>
@Model.ToString()
</div>
```

When tested in IE I keep getting the same result appended, but in Firefox it works fine.

Any way to make this code compatible with IE or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the following in the document ready of the layout?

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
```

Si

Comment: looking at your answer i understood it's a caching problem so i added this: `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]` on top of the controller that caused the problem. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, IE is particularly aggressive with its cache.